# Cannot login with correct username and password anymore

Tags: login, password, username

I can't log in with my correct username and password.

I get the message:

`ERROR: The password you entered for the username is incorrect.`

I have tried all the tips for fixing this problem I have found on WordPress forums such as:

1. Deactivating plugins by renaming plugin folder to `plugin_backup`.
2. Deleting browser cookies and cache.
3. Deleted the custom theme I was using.

But none of these things seemed to help because I still can't log in.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/reset-your-password/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've tried clicking on the "Your post password?" link below the login, and are (for some reason) unable to receive the resulting email.

If you have direct access to the database, you can update the password directly:

```
update wp_users set user_pass=md5('my_new_password') where user_name='my_login');
```

Comment: UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass=[insert MD5 hash here] where ...; from here: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/reset-your-password/

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried all the basic troubleshooting steps and you're still unable to log into your WordPress account, it could be that the password for your user in the WordPress database has become corrupted or changed. To fix this, you can manually reset your WordPress password through phpMyAdmin.

Here's a step by step guide:

Login to your hosting control panel: You will first need to login to your hosting control panel (cPanel, Plesk, etc.).

Access phpMyAdmin: Once you've logged into your control panel, you need to find and access phpMyAdmin. In most cases, this will be under the "Databases" section.

Select your WordPress database: Once you're in phpMyAdmin, you need to find and select the database that your WordPress site is using. If you're not sure which database is being used, you can check the wp-config.php file located in the root directory of your WordPress installation.

Navigate to the wp_users table: In your WordPress database, find and click on the table named wp_users (the prefix wp_ might be different if you have changed it during installation).

Edit the user: Find your username in the user_login column, then click the 'Edit' button.

Change your password: You'll see your username, password, and other information. The password is stored as an MD5 hash for security. To change it, locate the user_pass column, select 'MD5' from the dropdown menu and then enter your new password in the 'Value' column.

Save your changes: Click the 'Go' button at the bottom to save your changes.

Now try to login to your WordPress admin dashboard with the new password.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to WP CLI, you can use [the `user reset-password` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/reset-password/) to easily reset a user's password.